# When to use discrete JFETs?

Tags: transistors, jfet

JFETs have lost importance and many parts are being gradually discontinued. However, due to the depletion type operation and other properties, I believe that even now in the 2020ies, there are still **unique usecases** for them, in which they either excel or in which the more ubiquitous BJTs and enhancement MOSFETs simply cannot work.

I thought it would be good to have a place to collect these applications of discrete JFET that is still up to date. I think it would be great to have only one application per answer.

Comment: One would assume you did some research already to discover all Electret mics have a JFET

Comment: YOu might be better off copying an MOT or NSC application book from archive.org or writing you own reader's digest.  Start a contest submit a prize to the best JFET design

Comment: You're misunderstanding the point of this site. It's for asking specific questions about electronic design and getting answers to those questions. Building lists and holding open-ended discussions are off-topic.

Comment: Makes me think that it should require moderator action to _create_ a community wiki, not only to convert it.

Comment: @pipe there was and I added as one specific criterion "if it is worthwile". Looks like it was judged so. But if a majority agree, it can be deleted.

Comment: @tobalt My bad, I see now that all the information is available in the post activity history, not only edits.

Answer (score 3):

### Bipolar current limiter

Bipolar current limiters can be very easily made with a JFET and - in the simplest case - two resistors. Slightly better performance can be obtained when using two Schottky diodes instead as seen below.

The benefit of this kind of limiter vs. a simple resistor limiter is its low resistance, when the signal is well behaved. A JFET with \$I_{DSS}\approx\$ 5 mA, will have an on-resistance of 100 Ohm or less. Therefore, these kind of limiters are very useful to protect low noise amplifier inputs from excessive input currents. Another advantage is that they add no leakage, as no shunt component is used.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftlAQ4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Electret microphones (ubiquitous and largely hidden application).

Discrete JFETs (individually and in pairs or arrays) can be used to make the front end of lower-noise amplifiers than available in IC form (for frequencies from hundreds of Hz up to hundreds of kHz).

They can be used as very low leakage diodes in precision analog circuits.

They are usable but not very good for constant current sources because of the wide process variations of Vp and Idss. Usually there are better solutions.

They are not very good for blinking LEDs or switching relays so the typical beginning hobbyist has little use for them.

Comment: regarding low noise amplifiers: aren't beefy BJT better there? Ive seen a website, where some guy compared various BJT and the best ones had around 0.2 nV/rtHz if I remember correctly.

Comment: @tobalt JFETs have comparable noise if you have a bunch in  parallel. BJTs need to be run at high collector current and/or paralleled in quantity to get ultra-low noise and that means large bias current (and current noise) so they're not very useful unless the source impedance is extremely low (eg. a ribbon microphone). JFETs have little gate leakage but they do have capacitance.

Comment: Adding to Sphero's comment: BJTs have low input impedance, especially when run at high gain and high collector current (both desirable for good noise performance). If your signal has high source impedance (> 10k perhaps) a JFET can overall be much quiter than a BJT, even if if it has more nV/rtHz.

Comment: @polwel Well a low noise amplifier (IMO) implies a DUT with resistance well below 100 Ohm, because otherwise, the DUT itself will create most of the noise through its Johnson noise. The low noise sensors I worked with had typical impedances of around 1 Ohm

Comment: @tobalt You are assuming room temperature, which is not always true.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany True. For cryogenic DUTs, the low noise temp. of FETs always wins.

Comment: Source impedance can also be reactive, e.g. capacitive. Then its Johnson noise might still be low.

Answer (score 1):

Low noise, stiff current sink for CCD outputs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJKOU3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using a JFET rather than a resistor improves linearity. R1 improves drain resistance, noise, and predictability of the current.

Comment: Why a JFET rather than a BJT?

Comment: @polwel Because a BJT would need a bias network. That's more components and more noise sources.

Comment: Is a JFET here significantly superior to a depletion-mode MOSFET?

Comment: @Hearth MOSFETs usually have much more flicker noise than JFETs.

Answer (score 0):

JFETs are used as inputs to op amps (and amplifiers in general) when lower noise is required than what CMOS inputs are capable of and higher impedance than what bipolar inputs are capable of.

Most often this comes in the form of a differential JFET pair that exists inside the opamp serving as its input, but can also come in the form of external JFET source followers or ,more much more elaborately, differential or even complimentary differential pairs feeding op-amp inputs.

NOTE: You always want to use matched pairs for any transistors (any kind of transistor, MOSFET, BJT, JFET, or otherwise) being used in differential pairs. They rely on their symmetry to function. Since the matching of discrete JFET is often worse than for parts on the same silicon die, [this App Note from ADI](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/tips-on-making-fetching-discrete-amplifier.html) shows techniques to tune the offset voltage for discrete JFET pairs.

Comment: Using external JFETs might give some offset problems, though. I'm pretty sure you need them to be well-matched. You could mitigate that if you use a dual matched pair.

Comment: @Hearth I think it's a given that you would use matched pairs for differential pairs. There are very few on the market now. Almost all from a Linear Technologies but Texas Instruments just released one like a month ago. So excited.

Comment: Yes, but it's worth noting for anyone inexperienced reading this. You probably want them to be matched even if they're being used as source followers, too. Surprised there are new ones coming out, also!

Comment: @Hearth *Linear Integrated Systems (different from Linear Technologies which was acquired by Analog Devices)