# Protecting op amp from high voltages with leakage <= 1 nA

Tags: operational-amplifier, diodes, jfet, over-voltage-protection

I need to protect a op amp of a TIA from too high voltages/currents

[image]

From its datasheet, the LMP7721 support a maximum differential VIN Differential of –0.3 - 0.3 V. I cant use general diodes, due to the criteria of a maximum leakage of < 1 nA. I have read about using a JFET (LSK170A) as a diode, however even with this I get a differential voltage of 580 mV.
D1 and D2 have a breakdown voltage of 75 V with leakage current of < 1 nA.
Is there a better way to protect the op amps inputs or did I just not yet found the correct JFET?

Comment: Datasheet "7.3.7 Input Protection" says the input protection diodes are already in the package

Comment: well during testing it still dies

Comment: @bobflux thank you for your response, however during testing it still dies (using just the diodes and the 3.3k resistors, without JFET)
When I increase the resistors in the simulation, the differential voltage seems not to decrease. And I cannot just test different configuration because I am currently out of LMP7721

Comment: When you say too high a voltage, what kind of voltage are you talking about? If, in spite of all the built-in protection, you are still managing to damage the device, perhaps input clamp current is too high? Unfortunately the absolute maximum ratings don't mention a limit for that, but I wouldn't want more than a milliamp of input current, and I would be careful to size R4 and R5 appropriately.

Comment: The op amp is used in a TIA configuration to measure currents in the range of nA and uA. However short surges, were up to 1000 V may be present on the input.

Comment: Wow. 1000V is 200mA through 5kΩ. That poor IC. I think you need some serious clamping *before* R4 and R5, independent for both inputs.

Comment: And that 1kV spike doesn't fry the sensor that generates this current?

Comment: How is the TIA wired? Is the signal single ended and TIA input held at constant voltage? or differential signal? Can you show the schematic? If during normal conditions feedback holds the input at close to zero volts for example, then it's possible to clamp it with very low leakage, because the clamping component that is between the input and ground will have near zero volts across it. But we need more details...

Comment: The input is in contact with a vacuum discharge sensor. Usually, there should not be these spike, but sometimes they occur. 
@bobflux, there is nothing in front, which could get fried, besides the sensor head.

Comment: @Simon Fitch, this is more ore less my questen, how do I seriously clamp there, without having a lot of leakage

Comment: @bobflux the TIA is operated with a supply of 0 and 5 V; the non-inverted is biased to 3.3 V, so the feedback also holds the input close to 3.3 V

Comment: OK so tell me if I understood correctly. There's a circuit that sends high voltage bias to a vacuum discharge sensor, and this unlucky opamp measures the leakage through this sensor to measure the pressure of your vacuum. So when the sensor arcs or gets shorted, the high voltage bias is dumped into the opamp. In order to make a clamp that will survive this, we need to know how much energy the high voltage supply can provide for this pulse. Basically, its maximum output current, and also whatever capacitance is at the output.

Comment: @bobflux your assumptions are indeed correct! However, providing clear estimates which kind of energies occur is not really feasible. I would roughly estimate, that currents of up to 1 A for ns to us may occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to keep the currents below abs. max. ratings. The max. input voltage ratings of op-amps are not quite so important, but redundant. Adhering to the input current ratings, by means of current limiting, will keep the voltages in safe ranges implicitly.

Purely series current limiters add no leakage current at all, so they also satisfy that requirement.

In increasing order of sophistication:

- series input resistors (if ok noisewise)
- [series JFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/621525/237061) with suitable saturation current
- series JFET with resistors to make them limit at below their native saturation current
- [dual series MOSFET](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/567019/237061), with NPN drivers (needs isolated power)
- dual series MOSFET with precision op-amp drivers, also needs isolated power

That said, 1 kV is an excessive overvoltage, and 1 nA is a substantial leakage budget, so you can tolerate some shunt components. E.g. you could add a TVS between the inputs, with current limiting *after* the TVS device. This will reduce the overvoltage seen by the current limiter and make the limiter much easier to construct, as a result. For example, the limiter might have to withstand only 20 V instead of 1000 V.

Comment: It is important to keep *everything* on a data sheet below absolute maximum ratings if you wish your IC to function to spec.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Agreed. Let me phrase it differently then..The voltage rating is in many respects *redundant*. Adhering to the current rating guarantees that no overvoltage can appear.

Answer (score 3):

First I'd recommend setting the input common mode voltage Vref to 2.5V...3.0V instead of 3.3V because the excellent input bias current spec of this opamp depends on input common mode voltage:

[image]

Then, since this is a transimpedance amplifier, in normal operation it will keep its input equal to Vref, so any clamping component between input and Vref has close to 0V across it and should not contribute to DC leakage. In AC, it depends on the input impedance of the opamp, which should be calculated depending on what's in the feedback network and open loop gain.

[image]

So I'd suggest first a resistor and/or ferrite bead to slow the rate of rise of current when it arcs, followed by a pair of low leakage low capacitance diodes like BAS516.

Vref is used as a clamp voltage so it should be stiff, which means solid decoupling (low inductance ceramics plus a large electrolytic). If Vref comes from a reference chip that can only source current and not sink it, then perhaps it needs a TVS across it. Another solution is to use a shunt reference, which can sink current.

Then I'd suggest adding some impedance between the clamp and the opamp input, both for extra protection and to isolate the opamp's feedback input from the diode and cable capacitance.

Comment: Awsome anwser! I see some probems in adding R2 and R3 since it changes the potential of in regarding to Vref. One of the targets of theis circuit is to perform low input impedance current measurements. The potential of Vin is to be controlled and should not change (outside of fault conditions). Would ferrits significantly change the signal (I am measuring with 1 Mhz?).

Comment: And you are absoluty correct with changing the input bias!

Comment: It depends. First the input impedance of the transimpedance amplifier is (the sum of feedback resistor (R1 in my schematic) plus the open loop output impedance of the opamp (unknown)) divided by open loop gain at the frequency of interest. Zin = (R1+Zout)/LoopGain. It has an open loop gain of 15 at 1MHz (15MHz gain-bandwidth product) so you can get an idea of the input impedance without anything in series with the input and check if it will be okay. If it is too high then you need either a faster opamp, a smaller feedback resistor, or another design.

Comment: Alright i think will give it a try, do you think a TVS diode proper decoupling will protect the 3.3 V reference ic enough?

Comment: Yes TVS diode and decoupling should be fine. Small packages and ground plane for low inductance.

Comment: FYI, ferrite beads are useless against ESD strikes (or whatever this impulse is like) -- current quickly rises into saturation and it becomes naught but a wire link. RC filtering and diode clamping is the way to go (in this case: as much as can be afforded without compromising amplifier bandwidth and stability).

Comment: Aw crap. How about an iron powder toroid inductor?