# Overvoltage protection with ultra low leakage current for 3.3 V

Tags: circuit-design, diodes, jfet, over-voltage-protection

I am in search of a method to implement voltage clamping or overvoltage protection for a sense line operating at 3.3V, with an ultra-low leakage current of ideally less than 1 nA. If achieving less than 1 nA is not feasible, a leakage current of less than 10 nA would be acceptable. The overvoltage condition threshold is set at 4V. The circuit needs to protect against transient voltage surges, typically ranging from 1 mA to less than 100 mA, though protection up to 50 mA would be sufficient. Without protection, the voltage could potentially spike up to 1000V; however, with adequate clamping, it should never approach this level.

One potential solution that I am considering involves using JFETs (Junction Field-Effect Transistors). Can anyone confirm if this approach is effective for this application? Additionally, I would appreciate any alternative suggestions or recommendations for ensuring reliable overvoltage protection while maintaining ultra-low leakage currents.

EDIT 1:
The sense line carries a signal up to 1 Mhz.

EDIT 2:
The sense line carries a current signal (nA - mA) of up to 1 Mhz at a steady 3.3V (through a TIA). This is a follow up question for [Protecting op amp from high voltages with leakage <= 1 nA](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/671147/protecting-op-amp-from-high-voltages-with-leakage-1-na). I liked and tried to implement of tobalt's anwser. However due to adjustable gain a single current limiter would not be feasable. Wheras an overvoltage protection would work over multiple gains.

Comment: You describe transient voltage surges in terms of current which does not make sense. Please clarify.

Comment: If the signal goes up to 1MHz, I assume the nA leakage spec only applies to DC and not extra capacitance added by the clamping circuit?

Comment: This smells like an X-Y problem: you are looking for a solution to problem Y (supply voltage overshoot) caused by problem X. Please provide information about problem X (what is causing the voltage overshoot in the first place). And, what else is connected to the supply?

Comment: @bobflu the nA spec also applies to the 1 Mhz so capacity to GND is a no no.

Comment: @TimWilliams I am working with devices which measure the properties of plasma. Therefore the circuit I am searching for is basically the input circuit.

Comment: what would speak against using a JFET (CMPF4391) as diode (see https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa058/sboa058.pdf)? I see that it would propably not achieve perfect 4 V.

Comment: @tobalt this is actually my old question. And there was good feedback, which however did not solve my problem, thus I changed my question a bit. The problem with the anwser is that I use different gains for the TIA. -> A single current limit does only work for one gain. A voltage limiter works with multiple gain stages.

Comment: 10nA leakage at 1MHz seems very difficult to achieve on normal PCB. It would require capacitance at femtofarad level. Even a short trace will already have enough capacitance to leak more than that, so you need to surround it with guard rails. But then the opamp follower for the guard will probably have input capacitance too large for the spec also.

Comment: @jpa guard rails are in place! I mean this is the target spec, if it is not feasable, then the specs must be updated.

Comment: @Olgidos If you already have a guard rail voltage tracking the signal available, you should include that information in the question. It permits more solutions, including making the one suggested by user69795 very easy to implement.

Comment: @Olgidos then maybe I didn't get the point across in the other question: **you don't need any overvoltage protection to protect any IC!**. Limiting current to abs. max. ratings is sufficient. The gains don't matter..You only protect the input pin from over current and in so doing, realize a sufficient and adaptive overvoltage protection **implicitly**.

Comment: @tobalt My problem is that, I have 4 current ranges (0-330nA, 0-3.3 uA, 0-33 uA, 0-660uA). When I for example configure a current limiter for 1 mA while using the 330nA range, my op amp is still dead. while it is fine when using the 660 nA range. While when implementing an overvoltage control, it will protect in either case. Or am I wrong on this?

Comment: @Olgidos see my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way of doing this is to use diodes, but instead of connecting them to some clipping voltage, “guard”  them by connecting them to a voltage follower that tracks the sense line voltage. The voltage follower is then limited in its excursion, providing clipping through the diodes. For signals within the follower, there is no voltage across the diodes, so they don’t leak.  (This works for low frequencies. )

Comment: Lovely idea however not feasable, see edit 1. :)

Comment: @Olgidos voltage followers operating at 100s of MHz are feasible in the grand scheme of things; you have provided no information to suggest that this is not a suitable solution.

Comment: While this is the conventional solution, the positive feedback through the diode capacitance makes it hard to stabilize for a bandwidth of 1 MHz. Also 1 nA is a substantial leakage budget, so regular shunt components + series current limiters are probably acceptable.

Comment: @tobalt I'm not sure offhand if/where a reference can be found (likely buried somewhere in sci.electronics.design that isn't well searchable these days) but, Phil Hobbs did a bootstrapped probe amplifier with some rather high-performance transistors and got some preposterous fraction of a pF input impedance, at comparable bandwidths (I think it might've been under 100MHz, not sure). If nothing else, his email is on his website: https://electrooptical.net/ I would not be concerned about doing this with op-amps (a discrete solution is not required).

Answer (score 5):

Any of the following designs will work, each having different advantages and disadvantages:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVG1KV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All three will prevent the voltage at OUT from rising above 4V or so. They all operate by keeping the clamp elements reverse biased for all input signals below +3.3V, which keeps leakage current to a minimum over the entire "normal" range of input potentials.

On the left I use a simple diode clamp, and a resistance to limit current. This approach will provide lowest leakage current, which could well be under 1nA if you choose the diode carefully.

In the middle I replace R1 with a diode-connected transistor, which behaves more like an ideal diode, and will clamp closer to 4V, even as clamping current rises. The use of a transistor will incur higher leakage current, perhaps 10nA typically, but you can search for a transistor with lower cut-off collector current.

On the right I use a second diode to produce similar, more ideal diode behaviour. This will obviously incur twice the leakage of the left-hand circuit, but not as much as the middle one.

All three require a low impedance voltage source of about +3.3V. Resist the temptation to use a +3.3V supply rail, as an overvoltage at IN will cause a large current to flow, which this voltage source must *sink*. As most regulated 3.3V supplies are designed to *source* current only, they could fail to regulate when asked to sink this current.

When I say "low impedance" I mean low enough to keep a constant +3.3V even while sinking clamp current. The higher the impedance of this 3.3V source, the more that voltage will rise with current. This might necessitate more "ideal" diode behaviour, to keep OUT under 4V, which is why I suggested alternatives above, in additional to the simple, single diode.

Here's an appropriate sink, providing a 3.3V clamping potential:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyXiIJ.png)</sup>

All current is sunk down to ground, instead of some unfortunate supply rail. Adjust R3 to set the potential at CLAMP at exactly 3.3V.

Putting all this together, you might have this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOkmow.png)</sup>

I've added diode D1, to clamp negative going inputs against ground, preventing the various other diodes and transistors from being excessively reverse biased. If you can guarantee that input potential will not ever be more negative than -5V or so, then D1 is not needed, and you won't incur the extra leakage current that D1 would produce.

This produces the following relationship between potentials at OUT (vertical axis) and IN (horizontal axis):

[image]

Be careful how you implement resistance R1. It should not be a single resistor, and should probably consist of 10×4.7kΩ resistors in series. This will distribute the 1000V between all ten, 100V each, and also share the total power dissipated between them, to keep them all operating within their rated maxima.

Comment: Awsome, anwser! I will test this out. 
However does this also work without the resistors? I have some problems with johnson noise.

Comment: what would speak against using a JFET (CMPF4391) as diode (see https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa058/sboa058.pdf)? I see that it would propably not achieve perfect 4 V.

Comment: If you use a regulat Si pn junction (doesn't matter if JFET, BJT or diode by design) as opposed to a Schottky, it is strongly advised, to add some series resistor *after* the shunt component. This is because the to-be-protected IC will start conducting at the same voltage as the shunt. The series resistance helps to mitigate this, by always forcing the majority of the current through the shunt.

Comment: @Olgidos to be honest, this is the first time I've seen a JFET used in that way. It certainly looks to perform better than a regular silicon diode in terms of reverse leakage current. Unless there's some reason not to do so that I'm not aware of, if used to replace D1, D2 and D3 above, you'd have leakage in the picoamps.

Comment: @tobalt I considered doing exactly that with an example op-amp or ADC input's protection diodes in the place of D3. I'm still torn whether to mention it or not.

Comment: This does not seem like it would satisfy the "10nA leakage applies to 1MHz frequency also" from the comments. That would require less than 1 femtofarad diode capacitance.

Comment: @jpa Yes, agreed! That kind of capacitance is not the domain of classic construction, either, this is squarely in the realm of guards and impedance control. Also, squarely out of my capacity to answer.

Comment: I added another edit to reduce the confusion! (Sorry for causing that, and thank you for your insightful comments and answers!)

Comment: @jpa 10nA leakage at 1MHz isn't a meaningful requirement: a handful of electrons move in that time. A more meaningful requirement would be overall system response (gain).

Answer (score 2):

As in [my previous answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/671161/237061), I want to emphasize again, that I doubt that an overvoltage limiter is indeed what you need.

Your circuit looks approximately like below. By adding a series current limiter to the op-amp pin, you implicitly protect it from any potential overvoltage scenario. Also, the choice of the gain setting resistor does not matter at all for its protective function. Under normal operation, very little current is flowing through this limiter - only the input bias current.

You should design it such to limit to a series current safely below that given in the op-amp's abs. max. ratings. Typical values are 1-10 mA, so you could design it to limit at 100 µA, which should be plenty.

My previous answer gives various possibilities how to realize this limiter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv8pKi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I see. I was stupid! I did put the current limiter before the feedback. I'll give it a try! Thanks for clarification.

Comment: I have have the problem, that when adding a series resistance (as current limiter), that my TIA becomes unstable for lower gains. I for example tested with 1k. When implementing the series JFET solution, I have the problem, that all JFETs with Idss <= 1 mA have on resitance > 1k. 
Any suggestions, why the TIA becomes unstable?

Comment: @Olgidos the instability is because the series input impedance forms a lowpass with the input capacitance..You need a limiting scheme that has very low on-resistance during regular operation conditions. 1kohm sounds fine for a few pF input capacitance though

Comment: If the input is high voltage, you'll have a hard time finding a current limiting element that works. But if the input is transient limited (say by GDT, chip MOV, TVS, clamp diodes), that will do. As for stability, some capacitance from output to -input may be desirable.

Comment: @TimWilliams Indeed, which is why I suggested a TVS in the initial question. They can be safely below nA typical leakage and would relief the burden on the current limiter a lot to maybe 20-60 V depending on the exact realization.